# Type covariance with abstract class and traits in PHP

Tags: php, types, covariance, php-7.4

I'm developing a PHP (7.4) library and need to use traits for a new feature but I encountered an issue with parameter type covariance.

I have an abstract parent class like this :

```php
<?php

abstract class ParentClass {
    abstract public function parentMethod($param): bool;
}

?>
```

I also have a trait  :

```php
<?php

trait MyTrait {
    abstract public function traitMethod($param): bool;
}

?>
```

I'm using both of the class and trait in a child class :

```php
<?php

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

    use MyTrait;

    // implementation of the abstract methods

    public function parentMethod(int $param): bool { // change parent method parameter type
        // implementation
    }

    public function traitMethod(int $param): bool { // change trait method parameter type
        // implementation
    }
}

?>
```

The problem here is that I get this error  :

> Fatal error: Declaration of ChildClass::parentMethod(int $param): bool must be compatible with ParentClass::parentMethod($param): bool

It seems like I can't change the parentMethod() parameter type. If I remove the `int` type on the parentMethod() definition I do not get the error ! Even with a specific type parameter on the trait method.

Why can I use covariant parameter type with trait abstract method but not with abstract class method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Covariance and Contravariance are concepts related to inheritance, using trait is not inheritance.

**Note:** The above statement is not completely correct, I'll explain why at the end of this answer.

From the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits)

> A Trait is similar to a class, but only intended to group functionality in a fine-grained and consistent way. It is not possible to instantiate a Trait on its own. It is an addition to traditional inheritance and enables horizontal composition of behavior; that is, the application of class members without requiring inheritance.

**Why you see this error?**

Because `int` is not the supertype of **everything** and is not a pseudo type that represents any type (replace `int` with `mixed` in PHP 8 and see what happens). Also [Type widening](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/parameter-no-type-variance) doesn't allow to use an arbitrary supertype (you can only omit the type)

For example, let's say you define your parent method like this:

```
abstract public function parentMethod(int $param): bool;
```

Type widening allow you to only omit `$param` data type in your `ChildClass`.

> [Contravariance](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.variance.php#language.oop5.variance.contravariance), allows a parameter type to be less specific in
> a child method, than that of its parent

So let's say we have another class called `C` that extends `stdClass` and we define parentMethod to accept only objects of type `C`

```
class C extends stdClass {}

abstract class ParentClass
{
    abstract public function parentMethod(C $param): bool;
}
```

Now in `ChildClass` if we implement the parentMethod to accept objects of type `stdClass`

```
public function parentMethod(stdClass $param): bool
{ 
    
}
```

This will work and no errors will be issued.

That is **contravariance**.

#Edit
As for your question in the comments

**Why is it possible to type the parameter of the implemented trait method in the child class?**

Because traits are **copy-pasted** into a class, you can't impose OOP rules on them. That's why you can override a `final` method in a trait.

```
trait Foo
{
    final public function method($var)
    {
        return $var;
    }
}
class Bar
{
    use Foo;
    // "Override" with no error
    final public function method($var)
    {
        return $var;
    }
}
```

*The point of abstract methods in a trait is to force the exhibiting class to implement them (**types and also access modifiers may be different**)*

[The PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.abstract) states

> **Caution** A concrete class fulfills this requirement by defining a
> concrete method with the same name; **its signature may be different**.

**Update October, 2020**

Starting with PHP 8 the behavior of abstract methods in traits has changed and now abtract methods with mismatching signatures will fail with a fatal error and LSP rules will apply on them.

**Ok why is that ?**

This whole change started with a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75449) report, and there has been some discussion [here](https://externals.io/message/103032)

It seems that prior to PHP 8 there was some sort of a conflict in behavior:

- This will work https://3v4l.org/2pERT
- This won't https://3v4l.org/ouO0R

And also because `abstract` itself indicates a contract, therefore what you were questioning about is legit and now with PHP 8 you will be happy https://3v4l.org/7sid7 :).

Comment: I know there is no super type but why is it possible to type the parameter of the implemented trait method in the child class then (covariance like) ?

Comment: Ok :/ Traits look kind of broken language structure at this point :/
Thank you for your answer :)